# React: Passing attribute from functional component to class component via onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Both of these first two snippets appear in a class component.
Here's the onClick handler:

```
selectChoice = (id) => {
  console.log(id)
}
```

Here's where I call the functional component that generates both the id I need, and the onClick method.

```
<ReturnChoices choices={this.state.choices} selectChoice={() => this.selectChoice(id)}/>
```

Here's the functional component.

```
const ReturnChoices = ({choices, selectChoice}) => {
  return choices.map(( choice , index) => (
    <li key={index} id={index} onClick={() => { selectChoice(this.id) }}>
      {choice}
    </li>
  ))
}
```

For some reason, id is coming though as 'undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the function itself, no need to wrap in additional function:

```
<ReturnChoices choices={this.state.choices} selectChoice={this.selectChoice}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `id` given as argument from `ReturnChoices` to its caller function

```
<ReturnChoices choices={this.state.choices} selectChoice={(id) => this.selectChoice(id)}/>
```

Comment: this creates a new anonymous function on every render, forcing re-render of `ReturnChoices` even if nothing changes